# SharePoint 2013 mini "social" entreprise network

Tags: workflow, people-search, social

New to SharePoint, i need some advices about how to approach the following need...

I am using SharePoint 2013 and This should be done in a single site.

> social networking module:
>
> This module is a mini social network where the user can see his colleagues, post articles, photos, videos or links and comments. The user can see all his colleagues and each new group member (eg newly hired employee) is automatically visible and can see everyone.
> Users can create groups to share content. The creation request can be made by all users and the group may be active only after validation of the department head or subsidiary.
> The user sends requests to join one or more groups. This request must be approved by the department head or affiliate.

I created a blog templated site but i did not found out how to add/show people in that site or how to add photos/viedos.
I did not figured out too how to automate adding new people to this site(newly hired ones).
And finally the validation part... How can i deal with that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version (2010/2013) and edition (Foundation/Std/Ent) are you using?

Comment: Do you consider Yammer as an option?

Comment: @Supriyo I use SharePoint 2013 Ent

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev I don't know what is Yammer ... i'll take a look on the internet, but it would be great if you can summarise me what it is about...

Comment: @Karoui - Yammer is Microsoft cloud-hosted enterprise social network. More info here - http://www.pcworld.com/article/260517/what_is_heck_is_yammer.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two main approaches to social features in SharePoint: OOTB social features and Yammer.

### SharePoint OOTB Social

There's a [big hub about social collaboration in SharePoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662531(v=office.15).aspx) on TechNet, including overview video.

To summarize, SharePoint has quite a number of social features OOTB:

- SharePoint users can follow sites and each other;
- SharePoint users can create posts, so that other users who follow them see it;

  - It is possible to change visibility scope of a post
  - It is possible to add an image to your post (only png, jpg and bmp): [image]
  - It is possible to address people just like it is done e.g. in Facebook and other social networks: [image]
  - It is possible to add links, however functionality is not same as in other social networks: [image]
- SharePoint users can discuss posts of each other by posting replies and likes.
- There are also special community sites that provide features for organizing something similar to Facebook groups
- etc.

There is also a number of videos on YouTube about the Social Feed:

- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=SharePoint+social+feed

Every one of these features is also available via Client Side Object Model (CSOM) including JavaScript Client Object Model (JSOM), so you can create apps that would be able to interact with the social features programmatically - which is nice.

But please be aware that as it very often happens with SharePoint, it can look very good at first glance, but there might be some limitations without workarounds... So I would recommend to evaluate every single feature before you decide to go with it.

There is a post from Nik Patel about social features. He lists limitations for each feature:

- http://nikpatel.net/2013/02/10/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2013-social-major-features-characteristics-and-limitations/

But I would still urge you to evaluate every feature yourself.

### Yammer

[Yammer](http://www.yammer.com/) is a full-scale enterprise social network with a [wide range of collaboration features](https://about.yammer.com/product/feature-list/) and very deep integration into SharePoint. Yammer is included into some enterprise Office365 plans.

Here's a technet article of how you can integrate Yammer with SharePoint 2013 on-premise:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270535(v=office.15).aspx

In fact, it is possible to completely replace SharePoint OOTB social with a much more developed Yammer features.

Yammer also has an API, so you can interact with it. Here is a very good article describing Yammer and SharePoint integration and use of the Yammer API from Vesa Juvonen:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/03/30/getting-started-on-building-social-intranets-with-sharepoint-and-yammer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for "mini" like all contained in a single site, you should consider creating a Community Site and enabling the Newsfeed on that site. You can award merit for participation and the like. SharePoint can handle the video, though at times it's a bit clumsy. As for adding people, you can allow "Everyone" which would be anyone in your org with a valid login.

Comment: can you give me some links or example to help me understand more ?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=sharepoint+2013+community+site+template